# Есть хоть какое оправдание запятым?

Tags: пунктуация

> Посреди благолепия природы, благопристойной роскоши дома и
>   благочестивой тишины, по каменным ступеням, босиком, куда-то в сторону
>   и вверх устремляется нимфа в развевающемся одеянии.

Хочу оставить как есть.

Comment: Автор явно подражает Булгакову: такое же перечисление длинных сущностей с запятыми же наблюдается в часто цитируемом в учебных целях начальном предложении из "Мастера". _Однажды весною, в час небывало жаркого заката, в Москве, на Патриарших прудах, появились два гражданина"._

Comment: У Булгакова обособление, там различные обстоятельства (места и времени) уточняют друг друга, в этом его оригинальность. А здесь однородные (сближенные) отношения, так что немного разные конструкции.

Comment: Это зависит от субъективного подхода к классификации: у Булгакова можно увидеть _однородность_ в перечислении обстоятельств появления граждан, а здесь - _неоднородность_ пар вроде "посреди благолепия природы" (на каком фоне) и "босиком" (в какой манере).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Все ***благо-*** на месте, и хорошо, что они повторяются. Становится ясно, что это **художественный прием**.

2) Запятые тоже не надо менять, так как   обстоятельства разделены **на две группы группы** замыкающими союзами И. Это позволяет без особых усилий воспринимать текст.

**Примеры** употребления слов с корнем благо-

Если отвлечься от грустной стороны дела, можно порадоваться, что путь мой завершается в столь красивом месте ― с видом на море, дальний остров и все **благолепие мира Божия.** [Евгений Водолазкин. Лавр (2012)]

Выйдешь под-вечер на балкон, ничто не мешает взгляду; вдохнешь в себя влажно-живой, насыщенный дыханием леса и лугов воздух, прислушаешься к дубравному шуму — и на душе легче, благороднее, светлее, какая-то **благочестивая** тишина кругом успокаивает, примиряет… [Т. П. Пассек. Из дальних лет (1878-1889)]

**Благопристойность** требует, чтоб довольство и великолепие окружали престол, аки источник благоденствия обществу, от которого истекают награждения, ободрения и милости. [Екатерина II. Наказ Комиссии о составлении проекта нового Уложения (1767)]

Comment: Позволю себе поспорить Вами. Три слова подряд с _благо-_  — это, как мне кажется (я указала отдельно в ответе), слишком навязчиво. Возвышенные слова теряют в этом случае свою необыкновенность и воспринимаются как избыточные, приземленные. Даже в Ваших примерах 18 и 19 веков таких слов в предложениях только два.

Comment: 1) Повторение двух слов обычно воспринимается как стилистическая погрешность (это раздражает слух), но когда их три, то они усиливают значение друг друга, и мы уже относимся к ним благосклонно, более того, они вдруг начинают нам нравиться. 2) Примеры даны для того, чтобы проверить сочетаемость слов. В частности, меня интересовала благопристойность роскоши. Ведь не сразу ясно, чем она благопристойна.

Comment: Странно. Очень странно. _1) Повторение двух слов обычно воспринимается как стилистическая погрешность (это раздражает слух)..._ В Ваших примерах как раз и присутствует повторение. Меня оно совершенно НЕ раздражает. _2) В частности, меня интересовала благопристойность роскоши._  В Ваших примерах есть одно  слово "благопристойность", а слово "роскошь" вообще отсутствует. Простите, но я ничего не понимаю — что и с чем мы сочетаем?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова  У меня приведены примеры употребления слов с корнем благо- (только примеры, это обозначено в ответе). Из примеров ясно, что бывает благочестивая тишина, благолепие мира (природы), а благопристойность можно связать с роскошью,  а не только  со скромностью. Это всё, для чего эти примеры приведены. Что касается повторения, то оно, как известно, может считаться нарушением стиля или художественным приемом.  Здесь мы с Вами в оценках расходимся, но это не так важно. Редактор и автор рассмотрят наши рекомендации и выберут то, что им подходит. И всё будет замечательно.

Comment: Несомненно.....

Answer (score 2):

Думается, что ничего и оправдывать не надо — все запятые на своих авторских местах.
Какие-то отчаянные действия посреди воздержанности и умеренности. Мне нравится. (Не картину ли описываете?)

*— Бедная девочка. Босиком, по каменным ступенькам. В ночной рубашке...* (И. Лем)

P. S. Вот только слов с *благо-* многовато. Может, стоит поменять хотя бы одно определение? Например, у роскоши: степенная, воздержанная, тихая, пристойная.

Comment: Я сама эти "благо", поменяв кой-што местами, рисовала - довела до магических трёх. Было (оригинал): ***Посреди благопристойности природы, роскоши дома и благочестивой тишины, по каменным ступеням, босиком, куда-то в сторону и вверх устремляется нимфа в развевающемся одеянии.***

Comment: Выражение _благолепие природы_ лучше, чем благопристойность (это больше характеристика человека, как мне кажется), — правда.

Comment: Так я ж думаю-думоваю: стараюся. Эту книжку - из зарисовок - мы в Интернете будем "публиковать".